# Can SonarQube be configured to show code coverage in "preview" mode reports?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am currently working with SonarQube v5.6 and have a need to generate comprehensive "preview" reports locally before pushing the results to my remote SonarQube server. Specifically, I need to be able to see technical debt, code coverage, and duplicated blocks in the local HTML and/or console reports which are created when running the analysis in "preview" mode.

Currently, I am able to see issues -- new, existing, resolved, minor, major, etc. -- and nothing else. I would like to be able to see technical debt, code coverage, and duplicated blocks as well (at the very least, I need to see code coverage). Can SonarQube be configured to show these details in "preview" mode reports, via a command line argument or some other setting? I am using Maven and JaCoCo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported currently (version 6.1). You can track this ticket to be informed of the progress: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763

Comment: Thanks, Julien! I will monitor that ticket for updates.

Comment: So, the structure of the default "preview" mode HTML report cannot be extended or changed currently? Are there any metrics or details which can be added to it via command line args?

Comment: No, it's only about issues.

Comment: I understand. Thank you again for your help, Julien!